# Offer table not updating after new DB insert

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

Everything is connected properly, i have a table for product offers that is linked to my products table through 'product_id'. I have just added a new offer inside the product offer table and it worked fine, although, that new offer has not updated on the front-end website.

The offer table still shows only three products that are on offer, and not four!

Here is the code for the offer table:

```
<?php 


$sql="SELECT a.product_id, a.Options_id, b.product_name, b.product_price, b.product_url, d.product_id, d.image_id, e.filename, e.image_id, h.product_id, h.Offer_price
FROM ProductOptions a
JOIN Products b ON a.product_id = b.product_id
JOIN ProductImage d ON d.product_id = b.product_id
JOIN image e ON e.image_id = d.image_id
JOIN ProductOffer h ON h.product_id = b.product_id
GROUP BY product_name
ORDER BY product_name DESC";

$result = mysql_query($sql);

if (!$result)

{

echo "An error occurred ".mysql_error();

exit;

}

echo "<table border=1>\n<tr><th><th></th></th><th bgcolor=\"#DFE8EC\">Name</th><th bgcolor=\"#DFE8EC\">Price OFFER!</th><th bgcolor=\"#DFE8EC\"></th><th>Product URL</th></tr>\n";

while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {


$name = $line["product_name"];

$url=$line["product_url"];

$image=$line["filename"];

$offer=$line["Offer_price"];


echo "<tr><td></td><td><img src=\"http://www.ehustudent.co.uk/cis21318867/cis3122/Tiersco%20Pro%20BodyBuilding/storeadmin/images/$image\" border=0></td><td bgcolor=\"#DFE8EC\">$name</td><td bgcolor=\"#DFE8EC\">£$offer</td><td bgcolor=\"#DFE8EC\"></td><td><a href= $url > More Info </a></td></tr>\n";

}

echo "</table>\n";

?>
```

Surely the while loop will continue to update when new offers are inserted into the DB

Comment: Simplify your SQL query until you get it to return all 4 results. Then build it back up, one step at a time, until you get only 3 results. The problem has to be in there.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, i have simplified it so it only shows the offer price and all four have appeared, no i just need to add the additional fields, thank you

Comment: I would add in one join at a time. Run it after you add each join. At some point, you'll run into the issue.

Comment: The issue begins when i add the two image Joins: $sql="SELECT h.product_id, h.Offer_price, b.product_id, b.product_name, b.product_url, d.product_id, d.image_id, e.filename, e.image_id
FROM ProductOffer h
JOIN Products b ON h.product_id = b.product_id
JOIN ProductImage d ON d.product_id = b.product_id
JOIN image e ON e.image_id = d.image_id
GROUP BY product_name
ORDER BY product_name DESC";

Comment: Ok, are you getting an error? Your SQL looks correct. Do you have corresponding `image-id` in both the `image` and `ProductImage` tables?